# Find which action is taking place in sqlalchemy user defined type

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

We have successfully implemented a user defined data type. In fact there is a localization strategy to save localizable values into JSONB fields, and adding a LocalizedString type we get/set their value using sqlAlchemy user defined type implementation with help of postgresql functions.

```py
class LocalizedString(JSONB):

    def __init__(self):
        super(LocalizedString, self).__init__()


    def column_expression(self, colexpr):
        locale_id = thread_locale[threading.current_thread().ident]
        return func.delocalized(colexpr,locale_id)

    def bind_expression(self, bindvalue):
        locale_id = thread_locale[threading.current_thread().ident]
        val = type_coerce(bindvalue, String)
        return func.localized(locale_id, val)
```

The problem is that I have to find out which action is taking place in bind_expression to add previous son items in update.

{'en' : 'Try'} After update -> {'en' : 'Try', 'fr' : 'essayer'}

Answer (score 1):

Finally I ended up with session events like before_update and after_update. Actually I found out there is no direct or indirect way for checking current action/command. This is by design since the phase of running bind_expression and column_expression is different than command creation phase. That is, you can not even know which command may be produced in this phase. Therefore, I saved a context-bound variable in before_update and then used it when required.

```
@event.listens_for(Base, 'before_update', propagate=True)
def receive_before_update(mapper, connection, target):
    if type(col.type) == LocalizedString and threading.current_thread().ident in thread_data:
        thread_data[threading.current_thread().ident].action = 'update'
```